# How should quaternions be used, and what shouldn't they be used for?

Tags: math, 3d, game-engine, spatial, quaternions

I'm reading up on quaternions, but struggling with understanding what they are, and maybe more specifically **what they aren't**. I started out thinking it was a superior way of storing an object's *rotation/orientation* in a 3D space, but I've later come to understand that it's "just" a way of *applying* a rotation to an object, to avoid gimbal lock. But can't a quaternion also be used to store a direction with an orientation as long as it's always relative to global world axes?

I'm coding a 3D environment from scratch. There is no global "up", like zero gravity. When making the `class Camera` (and later, any form of Player/Pawn, an possibly any spawnable object) it needs a position and a rotation/orientation. Can/should this orientation be stored as a quaternion (always relative to the global world axes), or should two vectors be stored for "forwardDirection" and "upDirection" instead?

If stored as one quaternion I probably often need to get "decode" it to get "forwardDirection" to trace what a player is looking at. But if stored as separate vectors I need to "encode" it to a quaternion to avoid gimbal lock when orienting.

Since quaternions are just 4 floats, memory is saved by this compared to using two vector3 (6 floats). But the processing needed to convert from quat to forward-vector might nullify the worth.

Or am I still completely misunderstanding how I can use quaternions?

Comment: For me quaternions are transformations from one coordinate system to another with the advantage of an easy "chaining rule". From that point of view one needs a reference system to start from.

Comment: @mikuszefski Well, I was thinking that the transformation would be from "identity" in any cases. E.g that the object's orientation variable describes the rotation from "world axes" to "local axes"

Comment: To some extend yes, as you will reference to an fixed but arbitrary base. However, if you have `p` transforming your base in system `S` and `r` transforming it into `T` than `r p*` transforms `S` to `T` (just the typical trangle for linear transformations) or (if I remember correctly) describes `T` in the coordinate system of `S`  ( I got in contact with quaternions mainly to align  coordinate systems from different measurement devices measuring positions and orientation of a robot arm)